Is it grammatically correct to say "I dislike people who don't "think important" their birthdays or anyone else's?
My main question is if "think important" is correct or if it would have to be worded differently like "think it is important" or "think of importance"

There isn't enough information here. The two words think important can appear together, but not as they appear in the question title. Please [edit] your question to include exactly the sentence you are asking about (you can use > at the beginning of a line to indicate a quote and set it off from your question text).

What you're asking is not entirely clear. Please give us the complete sentences that you're asking about.

There's no inversion in the OP's example. "Important" is a preposed complement.


I dislike people who don't think important their birthdays or anyone else's?

This is probably grammatically correct, though a very unusual way to convey the information.
I'd say it is a case of complement preposing, where the basic version would be

I dislike people who don't think their birthdays or anyone else's
important,

where "important" is predicative complement of "think".
Some grammars have an analysis of the basic version in which "their birthdays or anyone else's important" is a verbless clause (technically a 'small' clause).

Though not common, the construction can be found in the wild. I got the most hits in the records of British parliament.

I should like to give him that credit and my thanks and the thanks of
the people of Caithness for what he did: I thought important this
call by the noble Lord, Lord Kearton, speaking as someone with wide
experience in industry as well as an intimate knowledge of the United
Kingdom Atomic Energy Authority, to focus and give a sense of urgency
to the fast reactor project: I think that this is extremely important:
I am quite sure this six years' proposal is utterly unsound, and still
more do I think unsound this new attitude which I have already
referred to, that we " must take it or leave it”
The Conservative Government of that day did not think necessary
the precautions which thirty years later it was declared were
necessary
Some may think strange the idea of a police officer dealing with
olives or surpluses of agricultural produce.
Mr. Mitchell-Thompson was sure the House would think absurd the
retention of the term "Commander-in-Chief"


A strong motivation for switching the order in VERB X (to be) Y so that it reads VERB Y X is when X is a much heavier syntactic element than is Y. It may be that these heavier constructions are more common in “stuffier”, more formal writings. American Law Review: “[C]anon law did not consider null and void a marriage contracted without the ecclesiastical sanction and publication of bans when followed by conjugal habitation, [...]” Another such example: “[N]or will God hold blameless the person who does not revise the indictment of one who was unjustly condemned.”

Few native speakers would say it that way, with "think important". It strikes me as an unnatural 18th century  construction. This would be more likely:

I don't like people who think birthdays are unimportant.

And if you want to have a clause instead of a noun like "birthdays", you would say "don't think it important":

I don't like people who don't think it important to celebrate birthdays.

But that is still something you won't hear very often. This is a more colloquial and likely form:

I don't like people who don't think it's important to celebrate birthdays.


A slightly more probable version would be I dislike people who don't think birthdays important - theirs or anyone else's

@PhilSweet  "think birthdays important" seems to me to be a more educated construction  than "think birthdays are..." and for that reason I'd say it is less likely.  It's perfectly idiomatic but that speaker has a higher-than-average "grade reading level"

I think it unlikely that many native speakers would often word it that way.

What way, @PaulTanenbaum? "think important" + direct object?

@TimR, there was an irony embedded in my comment: “think it unlikely.”

@PaulTanenbaum Yes, I thought that the case, but I wasn't sure.

@TimR, do you think it necessary for us to continue thus?

Seeing that you have resorted to the more likely "think it necessary" I can now let it be.
